# Would Asking for Feedback about my Notes be Off-Topic/Asking for Advice?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I am writing some notes about stochastic integration as a way to increase my understanding of the subject since I am learning it for the first time.

It's about a 10 page PDF file in LateX.

I assume it would probably be off topic to post a link to it and ask for feedback (if there are errors, if parts are unclear, etc.), but I just wanted to double-check.

Also, assuming it is off-topic, does anyone know where I could ask for feedback for such a thing?

Answer (score 17):

Questions on Stack Exchange are supposed to be both concise and self-contained. Posting a ten page PDF does not fit well with either of these requirements, especially if the question is of a general nature about the whole document. However, if you could come up with narrower questions that could be wholly expressed in a post, it would not be inappropriate to link to your PDF as an additional, but not necessary resource for the question.

I suspect you might have difficulty finding places on the internet that would give good feedback on such a thing. You could try asking on chat here, or on the various math forums that are out there. If you happen to be in an academic environment, finding peers or professors who know about stochastic integrals could be a good direction.

Comment: +1 for mentioning chat. (It is probably a long shot, but on this site that is certainly a place where asking something like that would not be off-topic.)