# Where to post for feedback

Tags: discussion, best-practices, advice

I had difficulty finding a single, concise treatment online of the construction of numbers from the naturals through the reals. I have collected my notes in a document (<1,200 words) and before I present them as the concise introduction I had been looking for, I want feedback so I may correct any errors in my understanding or its expression.

My hunch is that this topic would not be appropriate for a math.stackexchange.com question. In the judgment of community participants, is that accurate? If so, where online might be an appropriate place to offer access to the document and invite feedback?

Comment: Have you considered starting your own blog?  You could then use the blog to post, invite feedback, and use for other such projects you would like to invest yourself into.

Comment: Somewhat related older post: [Would Asking for Feedback about my Notes be Off-Topic/Asking for Advice?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23307) You might also try asking in chat - either in the main chatroom or in some of the [area-specific rooms](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26814) - whether somebody would be interested in something like this. (To talk in chat you need at least [20 reputation points](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) on some of the Stack Exchange sites.)

Comment: This is unrelated to your meta question (which asks about advice what to do in situations like this in general). In any case, I have left a few remarks [in the set theory chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47548181#47548181) regarding the topic: "Is there a single, concise treatment online of the construction of numbers from the naturals through the reals?"

Comment: You may view my profile for instructions of starting a personal math blog.

Comment: You could ask the Question: "Is there a concise treatment of the construction of numbers from the naturals through the reals?" and self-Answer with your 1,200 words.